# Отображение картинки в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть картинка класса `Image`. Требуется отобразить её в произвольной форме. Например, как в мессенджерах - у пользователя аватар прямоугольной формы, а отображается он форме круга. Какими способами это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно реализовать, используя `ImagePattern`. Есть несколько уже разработанных ораклом форм одной из которых является круг - `Circle`. Объединив все это можно получить следующее:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Image image = new Image("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/800840075311333376/515GX-Cc_400x400.jpg");

        Circle circle = new Circle(60);
        circle.setCenterX(60);
        circle.setCenterY(60);
        circle.setFill(new ImagePattern(image, 0, 0, 120, 120, false));

        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения будет логотип в виде круга, хотя оригинал картинки прямоугольный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]